# What is BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3 analog for BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2 path.native_file_string()?

Tags: c++, boost, path, boost-filesystem

So I try to port my old project (from boost 1.44 to 1.61) I found out that there is no `path.native_file_string()` in `boost::filesystem v3...`

So what is analog for `path.native_file_string()` in `boost::filesystem v3`? (I do not want to use v2 any more but I need such functionality as native_file_string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about `path::external_file_string` (there is no `native_file_string` in Boost.FileSystem v2 currently), the equivalent is `path::native`. This returns a string in the host OS's format, using a string type that is native for that system (std::wstring for Windows, std::string for Linux, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Looking here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/deprecated.html
the new name corresponding to

> native_file_string()

is

> string()